# thunderbird: force encoding for all composed emails to unicode

Tags: character-encoding, thunderbird

I am using `thunderbird` 68.8. on Debian 10.

I have received an email in HTML format, with what looks to be greek ISO encoding (`iso-8859-7`)

When I click reply, the composed email is automatically set to same (Greek ISO) encoding, even though normally all my compose emails are in unicode.

How can I set to always compose all emails as unicode, regardless what the original email encoding was? I don't want to "inherit" some weird encoding that somebody else has sent me.

Normally, the emails I send are plaintext and unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open Edit > Preferences.
Look for the "Fonts and Colors" preferences (in Thunderbird 68.10 you can find it in the "Display" tab, I guess it's the same for 68.8).
Then click on the "Advanced..." button.
I don't have a message in Greek in my inbox, so I cannot really test it, but I would recommend putting both Outgoing and Incoming emails as Unicode, and check the "When possible, use the default text encoding in replies" box:

[image: Screenshot of suggested settings]